# Проблемы с npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Решил поиграться на другом пк с React+ASP.NET вместо чистого ASP.NET, а для его работы соответственно нужно установить node. Скачал официальный дистрибутив с сайта, установил. А вот модуль установить не могу (npm install) - сыпет ошибки:  [image: errors]

Comment: Совет: если плохо владеете английским, воспользуйтесь переводчиком. Npm у вас установлен и работает. А вот запускаете вы npm оттуда, где нет проекта и файла настроек с зависимостями

Comment: Я тоже на это как-то наткнулся и был удивлён: работа npm зависит от текущей папки, он не может установить компонент глобально "на весь комп".  Типа, будет скачивать с инета один и тот же модуль отдельно для каждой папки проекта.  Эх, фронт-разработчики, всё у них не так как у людей... )))

Comment: Короче, вы пытаетесь нпм установить в систем 32. Просто в папку с проектом зайти нужно

Answer (score 0):

В редакторе Visual Studio  Code как пример, если проект уже создан и находится на диске, пример левой панели для запуска терминала, на примере Angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]